# How to extract the specific field from JSON log saved in field message using Logback and Logstash?

Tags: logstash, logback, spring-logback, logbook

I'm using Zalando Logbook to generate JSON log messages in my Java application. The log messages are configured with a LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder in Logback. Now, I want to extract the "custom_field" field from the log message, which is a JSON object, and send it to Logstash.

Here's a snippet of my Logback configuration:

```
<encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
    <providers>
        <!-- Other providers -->
        <pattern>
            {
                "app_name": "${APP_NAME}",
                "custom_field": "%message{jsonPath='$.custom_field'}"
            }
        </pattern>
    </providers>
</encoder>
```

The above example dosn't work. The log messages generated by Zalando Logbook are in JSON format, and I want to extract the "custom_field" field from these messages and include it in the Logstash index.

How can I achieve this? Is there a way to extract the "duration" field from the JSON log message and include it in the Logstash index using the LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder pattern configuration?